# Prolog - Infinite loop when closing SWI-prolog

Tags: prolog

I've written the code below in Prolog:

```
go :- write(">>"), read(X), process(X).
```

And do various things with process/1.
To catch any unknown commands I've added:

```
process(Y) :- write("unknown command.\n"), go.
```

The problem is when exiting SWI-Prolog by closing the window before the normal end of the program, it gets into an infinite loop.
I tried to search for what is SWI-Prolog calling when exiting like that but couldn't find it in order to include it in the code.
Any help on that part or an alternative workaround would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting reads and thanks for the input. The way I have implemented my loop is at the of each process going back to go. The program works fine (from what I can tell) except when I close the window of SWI-prolog.

Comment: Have you handled `end_of_file`? Which is read upon EOF.

Comment: That seems to solve it. Thank you! I'm still a beginner to prolog... Is it safe to assume upon closing that SWI-prolog closes the stream and gives the end_of_file atom?

Comment: @Syrko: I am not a beginner, but this term-wise I/O is still a pain for me, too. Try to avoid it as much as you can. Rather reconsult a Prolog program instead of reading - when possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the term `end_of_file`, too.

After the last Prolog term, that is when only layout or comments are read up to the end of the file or stream, `read/1` produces the term `end_of_file`.

Since (in many current systems) the action to perform when reading past end of file (on standard input) is `reset`, also subsequent reads will produce this term. And thus your program loops while complaining that that it does not know the command `end_of_file`.